# this is not defined in mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and then display it with vue using the `mounted()` method, but when I try it, it says that `this` basically is not defined.

**I'm not using NodeJS.**

```
<script>
"use strict";

    (function() {
        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",

            data () {
                return {
                    books: null
                }
            },

            mounted () {
                var api = fermata.json("/api/books");
                api.get(function(err, res) {
                    if(res.success) {
                        this.books = res.result;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Which gives me the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'books' of undefined`

[Fermata](https://github.com/natevw/fermata)

Comment: context issue. uses arrow like `api.get((err, res)=> {})` instead, or save the Vue instance to one variable first like `let _self=this`, then inside the callback of your api.get, uses `_self.book`

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this, create alias for `this` keyword, withing `api.get` you may loose `this` scope.

```
mounted () {
        var api = fermata.json("/api/books");
        var _this = this;
        api.get(function(err, res) {
            if(res.success) {
                _this.books = res.result;
            }
        });
    }
```